# How to bind a list to controller when using fetch and @RequestParams("params") List<String>

Tags: spring, reactjs

Here is the controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/order/add")
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject addOrder(@RequestParam("book") List<String> books,@RequestParam("addressid")Integer addressid){
   ...
}
```

Here is the request:

```
fetch(proxy+"/user/order/add",{
        method: 'post',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
          },
        body: msg,
    })
```

The msg  is like this:

```
msg = "book="+encodeURIComponet(params1)+"&addressid="+encodeURIComponent(params2)
```

**It works fine when I using postman to send a post request.**

But with the fetch request, the backend said it couldn't find param 'book'.

```
Bad Request:Required List parameter 'book' is not present
```

What's wrong with the front-end ?

---

What I send through Postman :[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLOna.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I find the problem is caused by the msg

```
let books = this.state.books
let msg = books + "&addressid=" + encodeURIComponent(addressid)
fetch(
   ...
)
```

The books is a variable from here:

```
<Route path="/buy/:books" component={CheckOrder}/>
```

I encode the variable before:

```
let books = "book="+encodeURIComponent(parmas)+"&"
window.location.href = "/buy/"+books
```

So it's important to encodeURIComponent right before fetch

Answer (score 0):

Book is in the body of the POST request, RequestParam is for parameters of the URL, you must bind the body to a DTO with RequestBody.

Comment: actually @RequestParam works fine in other controller to get the parameters in the body..   Sending parameters in the body through postman also works perfectly..